# Using the Euler method, construct an approximate solution to the Cauchy problem with a given accuracy

Tags: c, math, task

Pls, help with the item 5 and 8 (the problem is described in the comment in code).
Here the task:

Using Euler's method to construct an approximate solution to the Cauchy problem with a given accuracy.

Write a program that calculates the approximate value of the solution to the Cauchy problem.

1. The initial condition (a and s (y(a)=s)) must be entered from the keyboard.
2. The point at which the approximate value (b) is calculated must be entered from the keyboard.
3. If inside or on the boundaries of the interval [a, b] the function has breakpoints (points that are not included in the Feasible region), a message should be displayed on the screen with a proposal to enter a new interval. Feasible region can be calculated manually for your specific option.
4. The permissible calculation error must be entered from the keyboard.
5. The first approximation should be calculated for n = 1. Then, when calculating each next iterative value, the number of segments should be increased in dividing the interval by 1.
6. It is worth stopping the iterative process if the modulus of the difference between the last two approximations is less than the specified error.
7. If n exceeds 10000, and the required accuracy is not achieved, display the current answer and the current error with the remark "It was not possible to achieve the specified accuracy."
8. The screen should display the last total value (final answer), rounded in accordance with the error, as well as the required number of iterations.

   ```
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    //round y
    double round_y(double y, int count) {
            return round(y * pow(10, count)) / pow(10, count);
        }
    //function
    const double f(double x, double y){
        return 2.0*x*sqrt(y)-y;  
    }

    int main(){
        int i, n;
        double y, xi, yi, h, a, b, s, eps;
        printf("Enter value a = ");
        scanf("%lf",&a);
         xi=a;

        printf("Enter value b = ");
        scanf("%lf",&b);

        printf("Enter value s = ");
        scanf("%lf",&s);
         yi=s;

        printf("Enter value eps = ");
        scanf("%lf",&eps); 

        //Here the problem item 8
        //There should be a function here for
        //counting decimal places in error for further rounding
        //but for example I just write by myself count
        int count = 1;

    //Euler's method
    n=1; //Here the problem item 5 (iterations always is 1)
    int iter_count = 0;
    while(xi<n){       
        h=(b-a)/n;
        y=yi+h*f(xi,yi);
        iter_count=iter_count+1;
        //printf("\ny = %lf\n", y);
        if (fabs(y-yi)<eps){
          printf("\nDifference modulus greater than error\n");
          break;
        }
        //printf("\nyi = %lf\n", yi);
        yi=y;

        //printf("\nxi = %lf\n", xi);
        xi=xi+h; 
        n++; //Here the problem item 5     

        if (n>10000.0){
          printf("\nIt was not possible to achieve the specified accuracy\n");
          break;
        }
        if (y==0.0){
          printf("\nERROR Feasible region!\nPlease enter a new spacing\n");
          break;
        }
    } 

    printf("___________________________________\n");
    printf("The y value is %lf\n", round_y(y, count));
    printf("Eps is %lf\n",eps);
    printf("The number of iterations is %d\n",iter_count);
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

for `item5` you need the function `firstdecplace()`

for `item8` you need two loops

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//round y
double round_y(double y, int count) {
        return round(y * pow(10, count)) / pow(10, count);
    }
//function
const double f(double x, double y){
    return 2.0*x*sqrt(y)-y;  
}

unsigned int firstdecplace( double error ) //item 5
{
  if( error <= 0 )
  {
    printf( "Error at firstdecplace: argument smaller equals 0\n" );
    exit(1);
  }

  unsigned int  firstdec = 0; 

  while( error < 1 )
  {
    firstdec++;
    error *= 10;
  }

  return firstdec; 
}

int main(){
    int i, n;
    double y, xi, yi, h, a, b, s, eps;
    printf("Enter value a = ");
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    xi=a;

    printf("Enter value b = ");
    scanf("%lf",&b);

    printf("Enter value s = ");
    scanf("%lf",&s);
    yi=s;

    printf("Enter value eps = ");
    scanf("%lf",&eps); 

   
    int count = 1;

//Euler's method  
  int epsflag = 0;
  double approx; // approximation of  y(b)
  int iter_count = 0;
  for( n = 1; n < 10000; ++n )  // item 8 from here on
  {
    xi = a;
    for( int iteration = 0; iteration < n; ++iteration )
    {       
      h=(b-a)/n;
      y=yi+h*f(xi,yi);
      iter_count=iter_count+1;
  
      if( fabs(y-yi) < eps ){
        printf("\nDifference modulus smaller than error\n");
        n--;
        epsflag = 1;
        break;
      }
      yi=y;
      xi=xi+h; 
    }  
    if( epsflag == 1)
    {
      break;
    }
    approx = y;
    if (y <= 0.0){
      printf("\nERROR Feasible region!\nPlease enter a new spacing\n");
      break;
    }
     
  }

  if(n == 10000){
    printf("\nIt was not possible to achieve the specified accuracy\n");
  }
  printf("___________________________________\n");
  printf("The y value is %lf\n", round_y(approx, firstdecplace(eps)));
  printf("Eps is %lf\n",eps);
  printf( "number of iteration for the approxmation of y(b): %d\n", n );
  printf("The number of total iterations: %d\n",iter_count);
}
```